# Remove click event problems

Tags: javascript

I'm doing something obviously wrong but can't explain to myself.

The goal is to listen on a click event (START, first). If user clicks Start the second click listener should get ready but only fire if clicked on the particular element. If second click happens outside, the second click event listener should again be removed.

As simple as it sounds, here are my problems:

1. When clicking on "start" why is the `document.body.addEventListener('click'` firing?
2. How can I accomplish what I've explained?

```js
var Blubb = function(element){
    this.element = element;
    document.addEventListener('make-ready', this.makeBlubbReady.bind(this), false);
};

Blubb.prototype.makeBlubbReady = function(){
    var options = {one: true, two: false };
    this.element.classList.remove('disabled');
    
    this.element.addEventListener('click', (function(){this.go(options)}).bind(this), false);
    
    document.body.addEventListener(
        'click',
        (function(event){
            console.log('This shouldn\'t be ready before clicking "start"');
            if(event.target == this.element) {
                return;
            }
            this.element.removeEventListener('click', this.go)
        }).bind(this),
        false
    );
};

Blubb.prototype.go = function(options){
    console.log('Blubb go, options.one: ', options.one);
};

document.querySelector('.first').addEventListener('click', function(){
    new Blubb(document.querySelector('.second'));
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('make-ready', {}));
}, false)
```

```css
.second.disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">START</div>
<br />
<div class="second disabled">BLUBB</div>
```

Next is pretty much the same as above. Just to explain the 1. problem more. Why does the `console` logs `3` when only setting up the event listener on the body? I expected to behave like setting up the event listener on `this.element` which also just waits to get a click event..

```js
var Blubb = function(element){
    this.element = element;
    document.addEventListener('make-ready', this.makeBlubbReady.bind(this), false);
};

Blubb.prototype.makeBlubbReady = function(){
    var options = {one: true, two: false };
    this.element.classList.remove('disabled');
    console.log('1');
    
    this.element.addEventListener('click', (function(){
        console.log('2');
        this.go(options)
    }).bind(this), false);
    
    document.body.addEventListener('click', (function(){
            console.log('3');
        }).bind(this),
        false
    );
};

Blubb.prototype.go = function(options){
    console.log('Blubb go, options.one: ', options.one);
};

document.querySelector('.first').addEventListener('click', function(){
    new Blubb(document.querySelector('.second'));
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('make-ready', {}));
}, false)
```

```css
.second.disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">START</div>
<br />
<div class="second disabled">BLUBB</div>
```

Comment: I got scared after reading the title of your question :/

Comment: @void thanks for comment, changed the title to make it less scary :)

Comment: i think that you click on start => you pass on your first event listener, setting the one on document, then event bubbling, and trigger document click handler that you just set

Comment: For First anlyse I can say that you are binding the events for each time you click on your document. try to change the place where you bind your events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're using `bind` to bind a reference of the class to the listener, but `bind` would create a new reference of the listener each time it's used. Therefore you won't be able to remove the listener later on. To fix this you have to save the listener reference into a variable for later use. Also your binding the listener to the document therefore it gets executed instantly, to prevent this you could wrap the binding into a `setTimeout` or set the `useCapture` option to `true`.

Also you should consider making your class a singleton or destroy the previous instance because multiple instances would influence each other because of the listeners on the document.

Here's an example of a class using the techniques descripted above:

```js
var Blubb = (function(doc) {
  var defaults = {
      one: true,
      two: false
    },
    disabledClass = 'disabled',
    instance = null;

  function Blubb(element, options) {
    if (instance) {
      instance.destroy();
    };
    this.element = element;
    this.options = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);
    this.element.classList.remove(disabledClass);
    this.removeListener = setupListener.call(this);
    instance = this;
  }

  function setupListener() {
    var listener = onClick.bind(this);
    doc.addEventListener('click', listener, true);
    return function() {
      doc.removeEventListener('click', listener, true);
    }
  }

  function onClick(event) {
    if (event.target === this.element) {
      this.go(this.options);
    } else {
      this.destroy();
    }
  }

  Blubb.prototype.go = function(options) {
    console.log('Blubb go, options: ', options);
  }

  Blubb.prototype.destroy = function() {
    this.element.classList.add(disabledClass);
    this.element = null;
    instance = null;
    this.removeListener();
  }

  return Blubb;
})(document);

// setup
document.querySelector('.first').addEventListener('click', function() {
  new Blubb(document.querySelector('.second'));
}, false)
```

```css
.second.disabled {
  display: none;
}

.first,
.second {
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">START</div>
<br />
<div class="second disabled">BLUBB</div>
```

EDIT: You can also use bind the listener with `useCapture` instead of wrapping it into a `setTimeout`. I edited the snippet above.

Comment: Thanks for explanations. But I don‘t want to believe setTimeout is the only option.

Comment: That's right, you could also configure the listener to set `useCapture` to `true`. I edited the snippet.